# Creating a trigger in SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

Given the following question based on the database below.
a)  Create a trigger that will automatically update the quantity on hand each time that a product is sold as listed as a row in the LINE table. In other words, a line row is inserted as part of an invoice. Each line is linked to a product. Decrement the quantity on hand (P_QOH) by the number ordered.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWX17.png

Comment: Hardly familiar with sql, not even in the category, Friend just asked for help seemed the best place to get it, And yes I have tried.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: @Yardie If you have tried, please share your code with us.  We can be more successful in helping you if we have some code to look at.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create insert trigger on table Line

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerUpdateQty] ON [dbo].[Line]
    AFTER INSERT
AS
...
```

then you'll need to run an update Product table joining with inserted table. inserted table represents data inserted that triggered the trigger.

```
Update Product set Product.P_QOH = (Product.P_QOH - inserted.Line_units)
from Prduct inner join inserted on Product.P_Code = inserted.P_Code
```